# C# cannot load powershell snapin despite being registered

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am trying to use a custom snapin for powershell in my C# program. (The C# program is a modified version [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C))

I'm using the standard approach to setup the runspace:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(); 
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

If I run this as is and scriptText contains the command "Get-PSSnapin" my snapin is missing. If I run "Get-PSSnapin -Registered" then I can see my snapin. If I use Add-PSSnapin, then it returns nothing and followup commands that I issue (which are implemented in the snapin will return):

> ...is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
>   or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again

So, I amended my code to add the cmdlet to the runconfig:

```cs
RunspaceConfiguration runConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException psEx = null;
runConfig.AddPSSnapIn("mySnapin", out psEx);
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runConfig);
```

Now, when I run it, I get:

> error in script : Cannot invoke this function because the current host
>   does not implement it.

I tried both the x86 and 64 version. The snapin gets installed in the x86 programs so I did this by compiling for x86. If I do the 64 version, I get:

> "Error in script : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'mySnapin' is not
>   installed on this machine".

Confirming that this is specific to x86.

I also tried loading this as a module (desperation), but it doesn't work that way either. When I run:

```
get-command <command in mySnapin> | select Module, PsSnapin
```

The output doesn't have a module, just the snapin, hence it was silly to begin with.

I should note that this is installed by another program and I have no control over where it is install. I thought that might be a factor, but since it shows up with -Register I think it is finding without issue.

**Edit:**

I also tried `import-module <path to dll>`. This doesn't output anything and subsequent calls to functions in my snapin yield:

> error in script : Cannot invoke this function because the current
>   host does not implement it.

Then again in C# since I wasn't clear on whether the import will be preserved across calls.

```cs
pipeline.Commands.Add("Import-Module");
var command = pipeline.Commands[0];
command.Parameters.Add("Name", @"<path to my snapin .dll>");
```

Any help getting this rolling would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any luck if you try to import the snapin DLL directly?  For example, `Import-Module c:\path-to-snapin\snapin.dll`.

Comment: @Keith Hill Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it gives the same error as before. I edited my question with some additional details on my attempt.

Comment: Wait a tick.  It looks like it is your script that is generating the error `Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it`.  Does your script use Write-Host or Read-Host?

Comment: The code that I'm using directly does not but, it could be used in the snapin code somewhere. I don't have the source for that so is there any way to check from the dll or accompanying files? Suppose that it does use Write-Host, is there a workaround to fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, your app has to implement the PowerShell host user interface.  This allows the engine to send host output to your app and then your app can decide what to do with that.  See this MSDN topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface(v=vs.85).aspx